# Changing the in-place value of array with PHP

Tags: php

I want to modify a value inside JSON. Let's say I have this example JSON and I want to have the php change the phone number:

```
$data =    '{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "age": 27,
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type": "home",
      "number": "212 555-1234"
    }
  ]
}'
```

It sounds like I have to convert to an array using json decode:

```
 $data = json_decode($data,true);
```

Which gives me this:

```
array (
  'firstName' => 'John',
  'lastName' => 'Smith',
  'age' => 27,
  'phoneNumbers' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'type' => 'home',
      'number' => '212 555-1234',
    ),
  ),
)
```

How do I then insert my own variable value into the array please? From my googling it looks like I might be on the right path with something along these lines:

```
$number = '50';
$data[$key]['age'] = $number;
```

What it does though, is just add it onto the end of the array, instead of correcting the value in place of the array file.

Comment: `$data['age'] = $number;` And please - read the basics of the programming language you're working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to convert your json to PHP array usign `json_decode` function. check below code for updating/inserting keys:

```
$data['age'] = $number; // to update age
$data['newkey'] = 'newvalue'; //it will add key as sibling of firstname, last name and further

$data['phoneNumbers'][0]['number'] = '222 5555 4444'; //it will change value from 212 555-1234 to 222 5555 4444.
```

You just need to consider array format. If key exists then you can update value else it will be new key in array. Hope it helps you.